# With Express-jwt, how to use routing aliases?

Tags: express, jwt, express-jwt

This is the Express way of wiring the routing:

```
// routes
app.get('/grid', function ..
..

app.use('/grid', expressJwt({secret : secret}));
```

But when I use aliases to wire the routing (express >= 4) ..

```
var gridRouter  = express.Router()
, authRouter  = express.Router();

// routes
grid.get('/', function ..

app.use('/grid', gridRouter)
app.use('/auth', authRouter)
```

... jwt does not work.

Comment: I changed the questioning to make it clearer, you can re-open the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself and wanted to share it. We can't protect individual router aliases with ExpressJWT, yet we can protect the paths like we are used to.

```
var gridRouter  = express.Router()
, authRouter  = express.Router();

app.use('/grid/nestedGridPath', expressJwt({secret: secret}))
app.use('/auth/nestedAuthPath', expressJwt({secret: secret}))

app.use('/grid', gridRouter)
app.use('/auth', authRouter)
```

Sources: https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-jwt

**Update:**

As an aside, in case you have problems in getting express-Jwt to work at all, you can still wire it directly, e.g.:

```
app.delete('/grid/delete/:id', expressJwt({secret:secret}), myFunc);
```